# Rails export xls error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hello everybody who likes RAILS, i have a problem i'm trying to export by "ejecutive_id" to XLS but i'm not doing the correct code,

```
  -I created a select box where i can select all my ejecutives.
  -I created another select box where i can select by status_id.
  -I selected 1 ejecutive for example "Mogan"   (ejecutive_id = 1)
  -I selected 1 status form example "active"   (status_id = 0 )
  -After selecting both select boxes i click on "SEARCH"
  -After doing SEARCH i'm getting my results  (@list_policies this value in my code is before respond format)
```

Here is my controller

```
 ****PROJECT/APP/CONTROLLER/policy_managment/policy.rb********

class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController

 def generate_print_ejecutive_comercial 

        @search_ejecutive = params[:search_ejecutive]
        @search_status = params[:status_id]

        @list_ejecutives_comision = Ejecutive.find(:all)
        @list_policies_search = Policy.deleted_is(0)

        if params[:search_ejecutive].to_i!=0
           @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.ejecutive_id_is(@search_ejecutive)
        end

        if !params[:status_id].blank?
            if params[:status_id].to_i != 3
                  @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.state_is(params[:status_id])
            end
        else
            @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.state_is(0)
        end

        @status_id = params[:status_id]

        if !@search_dependent_dni.blank?
          if @list_dependents.blank?
            @list_dependents = Dependent.id_gt(0)
          end

          @list_dependents = @list_dependents.num_document_is(@search_dependent_dni)

          list_dependencies = []
          @list_dependents.each do |dependent|
                list_dependency_dependents = Dependency.find(:all, :conditions => { :dependent_id => dependent.id })
                list_dependency_dependents.each do |dependency|
                    list_dependencies << dependency
                end
          end

           policy_ids = []
            list_dependencies.each do |dependency|
                policy_ids << dependency.policy_id.to_i
            end

        end

        @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.deleted_is(0)
        @list_policies = @list_policies_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) 

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.xls
            format.js {
                render :update do |page|
                   page.replace_html 'table', :partial => 'table2'
                end
            }
        end
  end
 end
```

Here maybe could be the problem,also those are my links where i can export

```
     *********HERE IS MY VIEW***********
     <% form_remote_tag :url=>{:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial"},:before=>"load_close('loading_search')",:success=>"load_off('loading_search')" do -%> 
     <label>Ejecutive:</label>
     <%= select_tag 'search_ejecutive',"<option value=\"\">Seleccione</option>"+options_for_select(@list_ejecutives_comision.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]})%>
   </span>

   <%= hidden_field_tag :order,@order %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :page,1 %>
   <input name="Buscar" value="SEARCH" type="submit" /><span id="loading_search"></span>
   <% end %>         


    #HERE WITH THOSE LINKS I'M EXPORTING ONLY MY FIRST 10 VALUES 
   <%= link_to("Export Excel","http://localhost:3000/policy_management/policy/generate_print_ejecutive/generate_print_ejecutive_comercial.xls")%>
   <%= link_to "Export  XLS",:controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial",:format=>"xls"  %>
   <%= link_to 'PRINT PDF', :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial", :format=>"pdf" %>
```

I'm exporting my partial view and it depends of this

```
   @list_policies = @list_policies_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Here is my partial view and i'm using @list_policies

```
 ********************PARTIAL VIEW THAT I WANT TO EXPORT*********
 <table>

  <% @list_policies.each do |policy| %>
   <tr>
     <td><div class="nobreak"><%= policy.num_policy%></div></td>
     <td><div class="nobreak">
  <% if !policy.ejecutive.blank? %>
        <%= policy.ejecutive.name %><%= policy.ejecutive.lastname1 %><%= policy.ejecutive.lastname2 %>
  <% end %></div>
    </td> 
    <td><div class="nobreak"><%= policy.str_state%></div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

When i added this @results and i replaced it in my partial view i'm getting everything but i don't want everything , i only want by ejecutive_id

```
@list_policies = @list_policies_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
@results = @list_policies_search.find(:all)
```

Can someone help me with this please? i will really appreciate all help

Comment: Please take the time to reformat your code sample so it's readable. Doing so will encourage people to try to help answer your question. Hard to read questions discourage people by making them take extra time to make sense of it; We're all volunteers and we're trying to help many people, so the more you help us, the more we can help you.

Comment: "i have a problem i'm trying to export XLS but i'm getting all my results" doesn't make sense. Are you *NOT* getting all your results?

Comment: zorry my bad, i want to export by ejecutive_id ,but i'm not using the correct param that is my problem, instead of searching by ejecutive_id  i'm getting all values except using my condition

Comment: why are you using a ``LIKE`` operator in the query?  Is that really what you want?

Comment: No i don't want that, is just an example that my code is working,here in my code should be a param that needs to be exported

Comment: Actually my code is exporting @results ........but i'm getting everything and i don't know what to do to export by ejecutive_id

Comment: IF I PUT THIS CODE @results = @list_policies_search.find(:all,:conditions=>['ejecutive_id LIKE ? ',@list_policies ) Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT * FROM policies WHERE (ejecutive_id LIKE 69,70,235,1511 ) AND ((policies.deleted = 0) AND ((policies.ejecutive_id IN ( 76,77,78,79,80)) AND ((policies.state = 0) AND (policies.deleted = 0)))) MAYBE someone understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you remove `link_to` and place `submit_tag`s INSIDE the form to POST all your parameters into the controller method.

because now your `link_to` links in your view not have much sense for exporting xls you need...

Comment: ok thanks for the idea, but here is the problem
 @results = @list_policies_search.find(:all ) .............i need something else in this condition to search by ejecutive_id , can you check my code ,somebody told me that i need to find the PARAM

Comment: IF I PUT THIS CODE @results = @list_policies_search.find(:all,:conditions=>['ejecutive_id LIKE ? ',@list_policies ) Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT * FROM policies WHERE (ejecutive_id LIKE 69,70,235,1511 ) AND ((policies.deleted = 0) AND ((policies.ejecutive_id IN ( 76,77,78,79,80)) AND ((policies.state = 0) AND (policies.deleted = 0)))) MAYBE someone understood

Comment: Please somebody can help me?

Comment: if you need help for last comment then you have wrong syntax there: if you pass an array then you have to change `LIKE ?` to `IN (?)`

Comment: and instead of `.find(:all, :conditions=>...)` you can just use `.where(ejecutive_id: @list_policies)`

Comment: thanks i tried it but i'm near to the answer thanks to your message i will edit it again and explain all clear :)

Comment: glad to hear I pointed you in right direction, it would be nice if you accept an answer or +1 it somewhere =)